# Какими методами обязан обладать контроллер?

Tags: php, mvc

Если у контроллера должен быть только один метод, вроде "давай, выполняй что тебе нужно и верни мне класс Response или null если что-то не так", ну и возможно свойсво `name`, то почему бы не заменить классы на инклуд файлов с return в нужном месте?

Ведь каждый класс ещё и располагается в отдельном файле, в собственном пространстве имён вроде `Vendor\Package\Controller\ClassName`

Если же контроллер обязательно должен иметь какие-то другие методы, расскажите о них, о том что они должны делать и почему они обязательны.

Мой вопрос о том, **почему я должен оформлять контроллеры, как классы**.

Comment: вы определитесь сначала, у вас ооп или процедурное программирование. mvc вам дает в целом подход, детали реализации по вашему усмотрению, никто ничего не обязан иметь.

Comment: @teran вы не правильно понимаете ООП. Внутри класса код в процедурном стиле. Если контроллер не представляет собой какую-то сущность, нет смысла писать для каждого свой отдельный класс в отдельном namespace. Проще подключить файл, который будет что-то возвращать (почти как функция). Я прошу обьяснить почему я должен контроллер оформлять в виде класса.

Comment: @TryCatch к сожалению это именно вы не понимаете сути ООП. teran абсолютно прав

Comment: @rjhdby ну так объясните для чего оформлять контроллер как класс, если он не является самостоятельной сущностью, а представляет собой кусок кода, выполняющий только одно действие, как функция. Оформите это как ответ и я отмечу его как правильный ответ. Если вы не можете дать такого объяснения, задумайтесь над своим пониманием ООП и над тем, стоит ли каждое отдельное, независимое не от чего действие оборачивать в класс.

Answer (score -1):

> ну так объясните для чего оформлять контроллер как класс, если он не является самостоятельной сущностью, а представляет собой кусок кода, выполняющий только одно действие, как функция.
>
> Если же контроллер обязательно должен иметь какие-то другие методы, расскажите о них, о том что они должны делать и почему они обязательны.

Обычно контроллеры содержат внутри себя несколько action-методов сгруппированные по какому-то логическому признаку, а не "только одно действие, как функция". При этом контроллер сам по себе не очень соблюдает "принцип единственности ответственности", но если взглянуть на него как на "фасад" (паттерн такой), то ничего страшного.

А вот как решение проблемы "толстых" контроллеров и появляется решение оформлять каждый action контроллера, как отдельный класс-команду с одним методом "выполняющий только одно действие, как функция"

> Если у контроллера должен быть только один метод, вроде "давай, выполняй что тебе нужно и верни мне класс Response или null если что-то не так", ну и возможно свойсво name, то почему бы не заменить классы на инклуд файлов с return в нужном месте?

Действительно создание и вызов контроллера происходит в кишках фреймворка и вызов в итоге попадает в нужное место. И **инстанс** контроллера ну точно **один** раз создается. И много старых вещей написаны в таком процедурном стиле и живут же. Правда стараются смешивать процедурный подход с ооп только в одну сторону - ооп используется в процедурах.

А вот смешивание в обратную сторону не так просто. Несмотря на слабую "ооп"-шность контроллера внедрение процедурного подхода внутрь ооп вызовет кучу проблем - невозможно использовать инкапсуляцию, наследование, состояние, делегирование, которые нужны даже в контроллерах.

Некоторые из этих возникших проблем можно частично решить используя "include внутри метода", тем самым замыкая на себя проблему пространства имен, используя конвенцию именования функций, таскание кучи данных как параметров функций и так далее.

То есть мы получаем ряд проблем, которые необходимо решать, а выгоды от процедурного контроллера **не получаем никакой...то есть вообще никакой**.